# Free some space in Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I am trying to free some space in my hosting storage on Firebase. In the Release History list (Firebase Hosting console), you can delete deployed history. Is this can free some space when you delete old versions?

I am new to the web I appreciate if someone can help me here.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Old versions of your web site indeed contribute to the Hosting storage of your project. Cleaning up old versions that you don't need anymore is a great way to reduce the Hosting storage charges.

If you have more than a few dozen old versions that take a significant amount of storage, and you want to clean thos up, [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) who may be abe to do this automated for you.

Comment: Thank you!
I already removed them using the history list in the Firebase console.

But is still showing over 200 MB is full. My website is only 70 MB.
Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: I'd always give it a bit of time after deleting, since the stats in the console may be lagging. If it remains higher than you'd expect, [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting.